# Step function is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Show that step function is integrable

I think my logic is correct but wanted to check if I'm missing anything as the logic is too simple..

Step function is piecewise continuous as constant is continuous. If $f$ is piecewise continuous then $f$ is integrable.

I used theorems I studied recently and came up with that. Is there any logical issue?

*I assume that $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is bounded
Thanks!

Comment: How do you define “piecewise continuous”?

Comment: This is not true, the constant function $f(x)=1$ is a step function which is not integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I used the definition: If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(t_{k-1}, t_k)$ for all $k$, then we say that $f$ is piecewise continuous.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Then.. step function is not piecewise continuous? Is this the part where my logic breaks?

Comment: It helps to know the precise statement and the context of your question. If you're working in a context where the integral is built up through step functions, the worst logical issue you could be having by using general statements on the integrability of continous functions is circularity!

Comment: @befunctored Thanks for pointing that out. I added some context. Thanks!

Comment: @TheSilverDoe  Oh. if $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, right? I added some conditions. Sorry!

Comment: In fact, every non-negative measurable function is the limit of a sequence of  [simple functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function), for which the step functions are building blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the step function is integrable, but specifically on any *interval* $[a,b]$ where $a<b,a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, not on the entire real line. For example in $[-n,n]$ we have
$$\int_{-n}^n\mathbb{I}_{[0,\infty)}(x)dx=\int_{0}^ndx=n$$
and clearly as we extend $n \to \infty$ we get that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-n}^n\mathbb{I}_{[0,\infty)}(x)dx=\infty$$
If you are using $[a,b]$, we know that bounded functions (the step is non-negative and bounded by $1$) are integrable if and only if the set of points of discontinuity has [measure zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability), which is the case here because we have one point of discontinuity.